# plupload flash runtime doesn't work on IE8

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer-8, plupload

I am using plupload flash runtime in my website to upload the files as Attachments and send them via email. The website runs fine on chrome, IE9 and IE11 but not on IE8. And most of my users are going to be using IE8. I have been trying many different things but none seemed to be working. Can anyone please suggest me any solution?

This is my javascript code where I am uploading of file takes place.

```
modules.compose = (function () {
"use strict";

var config = {
    id: '',
    requestToken: $('meta[name="__AntiForgeryToken"]').attr('content'),
    runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
    maxFileSize: '200mb',
    maxQueueSize: 10485760,
    chunkSize: '1mb',
    pingFrequency: 100000,
    isUploaderOpen: false
},
bindUploader = function () {
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: config.runtimes,
        url: '/upload.ashx' + '?id=' + config.id,
        max_file_size: config.maxFileSize,
        chunk_size: config.chunkSize,
        unique_names: false,
        headers: { '__AntiForgeryToken': config.requestToken },

        // Browse filters
        filters: [
            { title: "All files", extensions: "*.*" },
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png,tiff" },
            { title: "XML files", extensions: "xml" },
            { title: "PDF documents", extensions: "pdf" },
            { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" },
            { title: "Text files", extensions: "txt,log" },
            { title: "Powerpoint documents", extensions: "ppt,pptx,pptm,potx,potm,ppam,ppsx,ppsm,sldx,sldm,thmx" },
            { title: "Excel documents", extensions: "xls,xlsx,xlsm,xltx,xltm,xlsb,xlam" },
            { title: "Word documents", extensions: "doc,docx,docm,dotx,dotm" },                
        ],
        preinit: {
            Init: function (up, info) {
                $('.plupload_header, .plupload_start').remove();
            }
        },
        init: {
            UploadProgress: function (up, file) {
                bumpProgress(up, file);
            },
            StateChanged: function (up) {
                if (up.total && up.files && up.total.uploaded === up.files.length) {
                    var parent = $('#upload-status').parent();
                    $('#upload-status').fadeOut('slow').remove();
                    $('#send-status').appendTo(parent).fadeIn('slow');

                    __doPostBack('ctl00$Content$btnSendMessage', '');
                }
            },
            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                var i = 0;
                while (i++ < up.files.length) {
                    $('#btnSendMessage').removeAttr("disabled");
                    var ii = i;
                    while (ii < up.files.length) {
                        if (up.files[i - 1].name == up.files[ii].name) {
                            up.removeFile(up.files[ii]);
                        } else {
                            ii++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            QueueChanged: function (up) {
                if (up.total.size > config.maxQueueSize) {
                    $('#upload-warning-modal').modal('show');

                    if (up.total.queued - 1 >= 0) {
                        up.removeFile(up.files[up.total.queued - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/assets/js/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/assets/js/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });
},
bindAddAttachments = function () {
    $('#btnAddAttachments').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!config.isUploaderOpen) {
            bindUploader();
            $('#uploader').show();

            config.isUploaderOpen = true;
        }

        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
},
bindSendMessage = function () {
    $('#btnSendMessage').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!Page_ClientValidate()) {
            return;
        }

        $('.plupload_filelist_footer').css('display', 'none');

        $('#uploader').block({
            message: $('#upload-status'),
            css: {
                padding: 0,
                margin: 0,
                width: '50%',
                top: '50%',
                left: '35%',
                textAlign: 'left',
                color: '#000',
                border: '0',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                cursor: 'wait'
            }
        });

        $('input[type="text"], textarea').prop('readonly', true).addClass('disabled');

        $('#btnSendMessage').button('loading');

        var queue = $("#uploader").pluploadQueue();

        if (queue) {
            queue.start();
        } else {
            __doPostBack('ctl00$Content$btnSendMessage', '');
        }
    });
},
bumpProgress = function (up, file) {
    if (up.total.percent >= 80) {
        $('#upload-status .progress').removeClass('progress-info').addClass('progress-success');
    }

    $('#upload-status .progress .bar').css('width', up.total.percent + '%');
},
bindTextareaLimit = function () {
    $('#txtMessage').limit('2000', '#charsLeft');
},
initAttachmentsButton = function () {
    $('#btnAddAttachments').prop('disabled', '');
},
initPing = function () {
    (function ping() {
        $.get("/ping.ashx");
        setTimeout(ping, config.pingFrequency);
    })();
};

return {
    init: function (options) {
        config = $.extend({}, config, options || {});

        $(function () {
            initAttachmentsButton();
            initPing();
            bindSendMessage();
            bindAddAttachments();
            bindTextareaLimit();
        });
    },
    validateRecipientEmail: function (sender, args) {
        var proxy = new ServiceProxy('/Default.aspx/', { async: false });

        proxy.invoke(
        'IsValidRecipient',
        { recipient: $('#txtRecipient').val() },
        function (result) {
            return (args.IsValid = result.d);
        });
    },
    validateSenderEmail: function (sender, args) {
        var proxy = new ServiceProxy('/Default.aspx/', { async: false });

        proxy.invoke(
        'IsValidSender',
        { sender: $('#txtSender').val() },
        function (result) {
            return (args.IsValid = result.d);
        });
    }
};
 } ());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late. Recently had the same problem. The problem is that you use
`headers: { '__AntiForgeryToken': config.requestToken },`
But by the specification it is not supported in HTML4 runtime:

http://www.plupload.com/docs/Options#runtimes

> headers
>   A way to pass custom HTTP headers with each upload request. The option is simple set of key/value pairs of header names and their values.
>
> Not supported by html4 runtime.
>   Requires special operational mode in case of flash and silverlight runtimes.

Since in IE8 can be disabled all other ways to upload files it will use `HTML4 runtime`, which doesn't have any legal way how to set antiForgery token. So your `server-side` will think that your sended file is not secure due it doesn't have antiForgery token and with drop with Forbidden HTTP status.

Conclusion - you are not abble to use AntiForgery token with plupload in IE8 in the how it is built in ASP.NET MVC.